# VS 2015 - Unable to add Controller or View

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I create a new ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2015, I'm consistently unable to add a Controller or a View (there is are no issues with adding a Model). Note: <strike>this does not happen when using an existing project</strike> It appears to be hit or miss with existing projects. Any ideas? Do I need to re-install Visual Studio? I've tried just about everything besides re-installing.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the text:

> > Error
> >     There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))'